# Android:select statement where clause two conditions?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is whereClString is true in assignment statment??
what i need is to select all from table where type = "tweetType" and Id = "userId"

```
    String whereClString = LikeDatabaseHelper.TWEETS_TYPE + "=? AND " + LikeDatabaseHelper.USER_ID + "=?";
    String[] args = new String[] { tweetType, String.valueOf(userId) };
    try {

        cursor = timelineDB.query(table, null, whereClString, args, null, null, LikeDatabaseHelper.TIME_COL
                + " DESC");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return cursor;
```

Comment: Any errors you are getting ?

Comment: Nothing returned back with the cursor.. seems to be nothing selected

Comment: There is no errors or exceptions

Comment: Show the table definition. And what are the data types of the values you write into those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String whereClString = LikeDatabaseHelper.TWEETS_TYPE + "='" + tweetType.toString() + "' AND " + LikeDatabaseHelper.USER_ID + "='" + userId.toString() + "'" ;
```

Comment: Unsafe: String whereClause = "column1='" + value + "'";
Safe: String whereClause = "column1=?";